# How to make IdentityServer client works with any origin?

Tags: identityserver4

When I create a new client in IdentityServer, I can set `AllowedCorsOrigins` to list of urls,but is there a way to make it work with any origin without setting specific urls?

I searched and if I'm correct,it seems custom implementation of `ICorsPolicyService` is the way, not sure if this is the only way,but if it's then how can I register it in identity server? I created the class but I
m not sure how to go further to make it work with identity server?

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `ConfigureServices` method of your startup, you can set up Cors something like this:

```
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
        });
```

Note that this is allowing any origin, but also any header/method ... you may want to change this for your own use-case.

Then in the `Configure` of your startup make sure you actually use your policy, like this:

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```